# Dynamic Nested Listing Item Selection in Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout

I am going to develop an ecommerce app and want to select different attributes of a product. These attributes are coming from Database and they are dynamic. Here is the sample screenshot:

[image]

Here we have three attributes:

Sleves
Neck
Design

These attributes and their quantity is dynamic. There can be more than 3 attributes.

Now in this case we have two lists. One for Selves, Neck and Design. And other for their corresponding value like full, half, without.

I want to select value for all sleves, neck and design.

Can you please provide me workflow that how can i acheive this scenerio.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit lost on exactly how your data looks like, how many lists are you getting? what is in each of these lists? Could you possibly post your code so I can take a look at them better?

In any case, what I would do is write a class that has a title and a list of values:

```
class Section {
  Section({required this.title, required this.values});
  String title;
  List<String> values;
}
```

And then, when you get your items from the database, you can structure them something like this:

```
// example
List<Section> sections = [
  Section(title: 'Sleeves', values: ['Full', 'Half', 'Without']),
  Section(title: 'Neck', values: ['Round', 'High']),
  Section(title: 'Design', values: ['Beioided', 'Print']),
];
```

Then on the UI, you go something like this:

```
class SectionDisplay extends StatelessWidget {
  SectionDisplay({required this.sections});
  final List<Section> sections;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: sections.map((v) => _buildSection(v)).toList(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSection(Section section) {
    
    return Column(children: [
      Text(section.title),
      Row(
        children: [
          for (var value in section.values)
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text(value), 
              onPressed: () {
                int index = section.values.indexOf(value);
                print("$index'th value: $value");
              },
        ],
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Hope that is what you needed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding, yes this is the exact case on my end. But how to select values from this one:

List<Section> sections = [
  Section(title: 'Sleeves', values: ['Full', 'Half', 'Without']),
  Section(title: 'Neck', values: ['Round', 'High']),
  Section(title: 'Design', values: ['Beioided', 'Print']),
];

Like, i want to select full from sleves, round value from neck and print value from broided.

So how to select these?

Comment: @AliCoder What do you mean select values? As in on the press of a button? If so, I've updated my answer to print to the console the pressed value, from then you should send this value to the bloc if you have one or to a new page. If what you want is to do it with a `StatefulWidget` you can set a list of selected values as state or add a `selectedValue` field to the Section class and use the list of sections as state.

Comment: I have achieved the expected result, btw thanks @h8moss